# Why the input not on the next line down

Tags: html, css

```
<label for="email">Insert Email</label>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="eg. youremail@example.com">

<label for="phone">Telephone</label>
<input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="eg.0123456789">
```

Why is this not working? It is messed up.

Comment: I have a feeling this is not javascript related. Check the CSS for the above elements. The default for input elements and labels is `display: inline` and you probably want `display: block`

Answer (score 1):

Add br tag after label  tags to bring your input to the next line.

Answer (score 0):

To get proper looking you need to insert them inside a `<form>` tag. If you just need a break, you can use `<br>`.Not JavaScript.

```
<form> 
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="eg. youremail@example.com">
<br>
<label for="phone">Telephone</label>

<input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="eg.0123456789">
</form>
```

You can get more about this matter by referring [this](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) W3School tutorial.

Comment: Thank You! I should have guessed!